# Webdriver with Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, webdriver

Selenium test (testNg) with mvn test from jenkins ,
I cant view the action performed on the browser, it is possible to view the real browser opened and performing action?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using **SeleniumGrid**.

You can then let the test run on a node, where *you* can see all the browser actions. For demonstration purposes, distributed and independent testing I did similar with teamcity for a regression-test project.

Basically there are two steps to setup the **environment**:

- Start the **grid** for example as background-service.

> - Start a **node** which is running within a *logged on* user context (also as Service or autorun)
> - optional: Start another node for running tests in background

- In your **tests** the creation of the the *WebDriver* instance changes like this:

`WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), capability);`

Here a link for more details to setup the Grid2: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Grid2

Answer (score 0):

No. In typical setup, tests from Jenkins run on randomly available node. You don't know which node is available at a given point. Also typically Jenkins nodes tend to run  headless browsers (like [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/)) since they don't have displays.

Jenkins tests are meant to be run without any manual intervention, like on nightly basis for example. You develop tests locally, see how they run in a real browser and then push it to your main suite so that Jenkins can run it for you. If you want to run tests from Jenkins and view test running live then look for paid solutions like [saucelabs](http://www.saucelabs.com) or [browserstack](http://www.browserstack.com).

Answer (score 0):

You can using [BrowserStack](http://www.browserstack.com). We have recently released a [Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/BrowserStack+Plugin) that allows you to view your test results right inside Jenkins. It's a paid tool of course :(

Answer (score -1):

In Windows you should not install jenkins as windows application (because in this recent version, Microsoft decided to give services their own hidden desktop even you enable the functionality "interact with desktop" in jenkins service), you may have to deploy it from a war file as follows:

1) Download jenkins.war from Jenkins official site

2) Deploy it by the command prompt : java -jar {directoryOfJenkinsFile}/jenkins.war

3) Now you can access jenkins administration on http:// localhost:8080

Hope that helps you !